# How to extract specific numbers from a 16 comma separated numbers string

Tags: javascript

i have a string of 16 comma separated values , and i need to extract the 3rd value from this string:
Example:
2563443220,2899228055,513347,0,#NA#,#NA#,0,#NA#,#NA#,0,15,15,2457550340,3556823919,6456282,0

in this case the result should be : 513347

Comment: `INPUT.split(',')[2]`

Comment: why dont people use google and commonsense at all?

Comment: Or `INPUT.match(/\d+/g)[2]`

Comment: Thank you. it is a special application and i sorted it out in another way.

Comment: @JosephChaaya if it is work then you can accept any below answer so, it can be closed

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method;

```
var str = "2563443220,2899228055,513347,0,#NA#,#NA#,0,#NA#,#NA#,0,15,15,2457550340,3556823919,6456282,0"


var arrEle  = str.split(',');

arrEle[2];; //access the third element
```

Or you can use regulare expression in this way.

```
str.split(/[,]/);

arrEle[2];; //access the third element;
```

Comment: Thank you. it is a special application and i sorted it out in another way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` method. `split` method breaks the `string` into `array`. So you can get your desired value from `array`

```
var str = "2563443220,2899228055,513347,0,#NA#,#NA#,0,#NA#,#NA#,0,15,15,2457550340,3556823919,6456282,0";
var result = str.split(',')[2];
```

Comment: Thank you. it is a special application and i sorted it out in another way.